# Create a trigger to assign value to a column after insertion

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table with (among others) two columns `uid` and `parent_uid`. I would like `parent_uid` to be equal to `uid` upon insertion.

`uid` is my **primary key** with AUTO_INCREMENT.

I have tried to set up a trigger as follow

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_parent_uid BEFORE INSERT ON seller
       FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.parent_uid = NEW.uid;
```

The actual behaviour is not as expected. Indeed, I get **0** for `parent_uid` whereas I should get **1** and **2** respectively for *25diamonds.com* and *24diamonds.com*

```
uid,seller_url,website_url,name,country,discarded,parent_uid
1,25diamonds.com,25diamonds.com,25diamonds.com,NULL,0,0
2,24diamonds.com,24diamonds.com,24diamonds.com,NULL,0,0
```

It seems that `NEW.uid` is not the correct way to access it.

Comment: Have you tried AFTER INSERT instead of BEFORE INSERT?

Comment: Yes, and I get the following error `Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger`. But I guess your point is not entirely wrong since what I try to do looks like a n "AFTER INSERT" operation ...

Comment: Check this answer, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19291561/4732334